# Android TabLayout titles localisation does not work

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have TabLayout with ViewPager and I have only two tabs:

- Table
- Map

I have several languages to support in the app, like for example:

- English,
- German
- Serbian

So, I use Serbian as default one, since the majority of users are Serbian speakers, but if I change to other languages, everything is localized correctly except Table and Map tabs, since they are always in Serbian.

What could be the issue?

```
English:
    <string name="tab_map">MAP</string>
    <string name="username">Username</string>

German:
    <string name="tab_table">TABELLE</string>
    <string name="tab_map">MAPA</string>

Serbian:
    <string name="tab_table">TABELA</string>
    <string name="tab_map">MAPA</string>
```

Here is adapter for TabLayout:

```
public class MainViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private LiveFragment liveFragment;
private MapFragment mapFragment;

public MainViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, LiveFragment liveFragment, MapFragment mapFragment) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.liveFragment = liveFragment;
    this.mapFragment = mapFragment;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0: return liveFragment;
        case 1: return mapFragment;
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return getPagerTitles()[position];
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return getPagerTitles().length;
}

@NonNull
private CharSequence[] getPagerTitles() {
    return new CharSequence[]{context.getString(R.string.tab_table), context.getString(R.string.tab_map)};
}
```

}

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: are you recreate the activity after changing the language?

Comment: yes, I even close the app and open it again, but still, the result is same. Everything is translated correctly except tab titles. Do you have another idea?

Comment: before setting the strings can you call the method of change language?

Comment: In this method `getPagerTitles()`

Comment: Well, there is no logic to change language all time whenever app calls getPagerTitles.

Comment: yeah, but can you call the method but no recreate activity.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. 2 min ago I was able to fix it. When you create your MainViewPagerAdapter you make it like this?

```
    MainViewPagerAdapter mvpa = 
new MainViewPagerAdapter(fm, getApplicationContext(), liveFragment, mapFragment);
```

I think application context look in to your default language (phone lang in my case).
Just try to to give activity context like: `new MainViewPagerAdapter(fm, this, ...`

Now somebody can tell in comment "that is not good to give link to activity context, better to use application context", so be careful with it :-)

Comment: Actually, it helped. thanks for sharing your solution